# GCP egress charges when your service calls other Google services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

If my public service hosted on GCP makes calls to other Google services (via those services APIs), is this traffic considered in-network and not subject to egress fees? Does anyone have any real-world data on this?

Comment: 1/2) Your question is off-topic. Factors that determine pricing change. Prices change. Answers will be out of date in the future. In summary, the only egress that is free is within the same Google Cloud zone using internal IP addresses. There are many factors to consider such as the source and the destination. Do not use logic, some APIs have both private and public (Internet) addresses which mean to be free you must configure private connectivity. In other words, document the traffic source and destination and then look it up here: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing

Comment: 2/2) For rough budget estimates, I assume that all egress will be $0.12 per GB. I also enable billing export to BigQuery and analyze billing data each month.

Comment: I'm not looking for specific pricing. Really, I'm interested in knowing if there's any cost benefit to using GCP over AWS if my service is going to be making lots of calls to other Google services. I suspect that there would be a network performance benefit, but I am also curious about cost savings.

Comment: Roughly, if the requester component and the Google Service are in the same region, there is no additional cost. Else, you have egress cost. The logic is the same with all Cloud Providers. However, in detail, and as John said, you can have some exception and you need to use private connnectivity to avoid egress cost.